# Track publicly accessible audio file request in PHP to increase the view count.

Tags: php, nginx

I am working on the music play application. In which the requirement is to increase the view count of each track when user play the track file in android application for some x amount of time.The location of the track file is on server and it is publicly accessible. I want to put view count logic on server side. I have tried to find out the logic but all I found is client side management using API to update view count on server.

If it is possible other than PHP, using nginx or apache than also you can suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you post what you tried and where you stuck ?

Comment: @Ravi, I thought to serve audio files using PHP, but it is not good way to do it.

Comment: so. you got the answer ?

Comment: @Ravi, No. Stil not.

Comment: I'm not clear with your requirement. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: You want to create API in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server can only count the number of requests to that file and how much data has been transferred (I assume you're making use of the HTTP protocol).

If you can map that onto view counts for x minutes, then this is it.

If you can't because this can be totally unrelated on public available files, then not.

Most likely if you bring the two data sources together (app view and download stats) you will get more accurate statistics.

Comment: yes, I am using HTTP protocol. Can you explain in brief that how to execute php script to update count when server identify any request to the data file?

Comment: This is normally not handled by a PHP script on request but by analyzing the server access logs.

Comment: How youtube manage to do this. Is it based on client side or server side?

Comment: I don't know how Youtube count views and I bet they won't share that (and they for sure change it over time) b/c they don't want to get gamed on their view counter.